# XAML Border vs Rectangle

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to get a window like this [image]

How should i get this and i am confused between Border and Rectangle in XAML.

Border is a container control aos its use is pretty simple to get, what is the use of ractangle as it can't contain any control in it.

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a [plygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon.aspx) as follow:

```
<Polygon
    Points="100 50, 100 150,250 150, 250 75, 225 50"
    Stroke="Black" 
    StrokeThickness="2">
    <Polygon.Fill>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
    </Polygon.Fill>
</Polygon>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) you can find some other interesting example

Answer (score 4):

Neither `Border` nor `Rectangle` will achieve this, you probably need a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) or something similar.

Comment: Will you please guide me towards some example

Comment: @MSingh: There are [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).

Comment: H.B.@ So i just create the desired shape, Set window STyle to None and set the window background to Transparent, is this the way to get what i desired?

Comment: @MSingh i would say yes. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30062/WPF-Non-Client-Area-Design-Techniques-For-Custom-W) to find some more guidance.

Comment: @MSingh: Something along those lines (you also need [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx)), but in general i would not recommend "over-styling" windows like that, users usually don't like it that much...

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer your last question

> What is the use of ractangle as it can't contain any control in it.

Yes it can't contain any controls, but you can always draw it in the background

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle/>
    <TextBlock/>
</Grid>
```

The user will propably don't see any difference. Why having two different Controls for that? Not sure, but my guess is that a Border is a shortcut to have a rectangle around a control, there might be more behind it, but thats how i see it. Also a Rectangle is a Shape, and it makes sense to have a Rectangle besides an Ellipse, Line etc.

Answer (score 0):

This path is like your shape, if you use Expression Blend you can draw it into the editor.

```
<Path Data="M20.5,0.5 L153.81876,0.5 194.5,41.181242 194.5,103.5 C194.5,114.54569 185.5457,123.5 174.5,123.5 L20.5,123.5 C9.4543047,123.5 0.5,114.54569 0.5,103.5 L0.5,20.500004 C0.5,9.4543067 9.4543047,0.50000197 20.5,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="124" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195"/>
```